# The Eu consent window doesn't show when the game starts

Tags: admob

I need to get EU consent from the user when they start up the game but after completing the guide on the admob site, it doesn't work.
I'm not actually sure if I have put the code from the guide in the right place because it doesn't tell you where to put it.
The ads work fine and there are no errors at all but the eu consent window never shows.

I have tried putting the code in different scripts and I have even looked at other people scripts.

I added the code from the guide to "PersonalizedAdConsent.h" class. Im not sure if that is correct but it doesnt tell you what to actually do.

There are no errors showing in xcode or unity and the game runs fine including the ads, but the EU consent panel never shows up.
It would be very helpful if someone could tell me where i am actually supposed to put the code from the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code, so can only assume you are calling it correctly.

Check the Testing section of Consent SDK.  To force it and also to show the provider list, use:

PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.debugGeography = PACDebugGeographyEEA

Don't forget to turn it off :)

Comment: I will try and put the code up when I get a chance, for some reason it wont display properly.

Until then I can say that it is basically exactly what is on this guide:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent